# Using saxon xpath in java on windows from command prompt

Tags: xml, xpath, saxon

I'm running this command on the commant prompt :

```
java -cp "saxon9he.jar" net.sf.saxon.Query -s:"xml document" -qs:'//Customer[@CustomerID="HUNGC"]//Country' -o:"results.xml"
```

I'm getting this : 
source document ignored - query does not access the context item

Does anyone know what could be the problem and how to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure about those `-s` and `-qs` parameters? Please edit the question with the exact command you're executing, and if the XPath expression is in another file also this file.

Comment: @JensErat Hello, yes i am sure about the parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning means exactly what it says: you have supplied a source document, but your XPath expression makes no use of it.

If you want to understand why the XPath expression doesn't use the source document, show us your XPath expression. An example that gives this warning would be -qs:"2+2", where the result of the expression is 4 regardless of anything in the source document.

(after your comment)

I normally use double quotes around the expression and single quotes within it. It probably depends on what shell you are using, but I suspect the expression has been passed to Saxon surrounding single-quotes and all, which means the entire expression is just a string literal. –  Michael Kay 7 hours ago

Comment: Hello, this is the XPath expression : 
-qs:'//Customer[@CustomerID="HUNGC"]//Country'
I'm sure there is a Customer element with an attribut CustomerID = 'HUNGC'

Comment: I normally use double quotes around the expression and single quotes within it. It probably depends on what shell you are using, but I suspect the expression has been passed to Saxon surrounding quotes and all, which means the entire expression is just a string literal.

Comment: I replaced my expression with : "//Customer[@CustomerID='HUNGC']//Country" and it worked. Can you please edit your answer by adding the comment so i can accept your answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You receive this error message, because you want to execute an invalid XPath expression (`XPath expression`) on a probably non-existent document (`xml document`).

Replace the strings `xml document` and `XPath expression` by the input document and the query you want to execute.

From the [Saxon Command Line manual](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xquery/commandline.html):

> **`-qs:querystring`**
>
> Allows the query to be specified inline (if it contains spaces, you will need quotes around the expression to keep the command line processor happy). For example `java net.sf.saxon.Query -qs:doc('a.xml')//p[1] selects elements within the file a.xml` in the current directory.
>
> **`-s:filename-or-URI`**
>
> Take input from the specified file. If the `-u` option is specified, or if the name begins with "`file:`" or "`http:`", then the name is assumed to be a URI rather than a filename. This file must contain an XML document. The document node of the document is made available to the query as the context item. The source document can be specified as "`-`" to take the source from standard input.

Comment: My question was incomplete, and i didn't understand your first comment when you asked for the exact command that i'm executing, my bad. Thank you anyway for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://ceving.blogspot.de/2014/06/using-saxon-he-as-xpath-command-line.html) is an example how to use Saxon as an XPath command line tool:

```
saxon () { java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query "$@" ; }
xpath () { saxon '!method=text' -s:- -qs:"$1" ; }
```

This is an example for the output of svn:

```
svn info --xml | xpath '/info/entry/repository/root/text()'
```